# Does holding a reference to values returned by mainScreen() and defaultManager() type functions optimize anything?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, variables, compiler-optimization

Some core classes use a function to return an instance of itself:

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager()
PHImageManager.defaultManager()
UIScreen.mainScreen()
...
```

If I assign the resulting value to a variable that I use n times vs just calling the function n times does it improve performance somehow?  For instance

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager();
fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(somePath)
fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(someOtherPath);
```

vs

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(somePath)
NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(someOtherPath);
```

or

```
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale;
let size = CGSizeMake(360 * scale, 720 * scale);
```

vs

```
let size = CGSizeMake(360 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale, 720 * UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it by running a lot of loops and check time difference.
the results are the same because `defaultManager()`, and `mainScreen()` are returning a pointer and it is the same as getting to the variable that holds the pointer , the only thing that "costs" (and it is very fast) is to get the memory cell which is the same time in both cases.
btw if a function returns a **struct** then swift language does clone it and it might be heavy.

```
func test(){
    print(NSDate())

    for i in 0..<30000{
        NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    }

    print(NSDate()) //12 seconds diff

    let test = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    for i in 0..<30000{
        test
    }

    print(NSDate()) //12 seconds diff

}

test()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I ran a similar test in a sandbox and on a device and came to the same conclusion.